How the string comparison works in php?
I was working on my website and noticed a strange php behavior.
Condition like this will return true:
if('0e1' == '0e2') {
    echo 'yes';
}

After testing a couple more conditions, I realized that php considers that '0e1' == '00e2' == '0'
Can someone explain how string comparison actually works in php?
Does it convert them all to some other type? If so, why and in which cases?
I would expect that even without a strict comparison, the condition '0e1' == '0e2' returns false

See the numeric values (represented as scientific notation) which you are comparing: https://3v4l.org/7HZQL  Good reads: Underlying philosophy behind php type comparisons and Convert a string containing a number in scientific notation to a double in PHP

This is because php isn't recognizing these as hexadecimal numbers but rather scientific notation, so when it converts to a decimal integer they are both zero because zero to the power of one is zero and zero to the power of two is zero. The opposite is true for strict comparison as that will return a comparison of the string literals. If you wanted to compare these as hexadecimals you would need to do
$hash1 = hash('sha256', '0e1');
$hash2 = hash('sha256', '0e2');

$hex1 = hexdec($hash1);
$hex2 = hexdec($hash2);

echo $hex1 == $hex2;


Perhaps transfer your insights to a suitable pre-existing page so that your contribution is better appreciated by future researchers.
